# Como substituir o ajax em uma chamada de conteúdo sem dar refresh na pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um dashboard para fim de aprendizado, até que cheguei na questão de carregar o conteúdo dentro de uma div sem que a página atualize, pesquisando encontrei uma forma utilizando ajax e jquery. Fui pesquisar um pouco mais a fundo e encontrei um conteúdo dizendo que não é uma boa pratica fazer a utilização do ajax para carregando de conteúdo.

neste link: http://wbruno.com.br/opiniao/parem-de-usar-ajax-eu-imploro/

gostaria e saber se realmente esse conteúdo está correto e utilizar o ajax para esses fins não é correto, caso não seja como substituí-lo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos esclarecer basicamente o que é [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

**Ajax** é um acrônimo para **JavaScript assíncrono + XML** segundo o [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/). Sendo mais "curto e grosso", o ajax é utilizado para fazer requisições ao servidor em segundo plano, ou seja, sem a necessidade de uma nova renderização (atualização) da página atual.

A artigo que você leu é muito bom mas acredito que seja um pouco exagerado. Não acho que se deve "abominar" o uso do ajax, principalmente quando ele atende as suas necessidades e as do **cliente**. E nesse artigo, o autor aborda o uso **exagerado** de requisições ajax que com certeza é uma ponderação válida.

Creio que o ideal para você é aprender como funciona esse tipo de requisição com o javascript "puro" e depois de enteder cada linha, analisar como é a forma usando uma biblioteca, que neste caso é a [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/).

```js
// Exemplo de requisição GET sem biblioteca
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); // XMLHttpRequest é uma API Javascript para criar requisições AJAX

// Define o tipo de requisição e a URL
ajax.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/p3d8t");

// Envia a requisição
ajax.send();

// Cria um evento para receber o retorno.
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

  // Caso a propriedade readState seja 4 e o status seja 200, requisição foi um sucesso
  if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

    var data = ajax.responseText; // Obter o texto da resposta fornecida pelo servidor

    // Retorno do Ajax
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

> As explicações para cada método e propriedades que foram utilizadas
>   para a requisição podem ser encontradas na documentação do método [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Agora veja a mesma requisição AJAX feita acima mas utilizando a biblioteca JQuery.

```js
$.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/p3d8t', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Essa é uma das principais vantagens de utilizar bibliotecas durante o desenvolvimento. Após entender o funcionamento, escolha a melhor opção para resolver o seu problema.